# Using GROUP_CONCAT in Dynamic MySql

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql, group-concat

I am working on a practice problem at CodeSignal; [problem link](https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/xwv7euMmeGRWxT77m)

For convenience, I will also explain the problem here. We are given a table called `player_statistics`, that contains information regarding player name, number of passes, number of catches, distance covered.

Here is sample data from this table;

```
player_name|pass|run|catch

Gareth Bale| 30|500|20
Ryan Giggs | 35|NULL|30
Sergio Ramos|28|200|40
Wayne Rooney|30|400|40
```

The goal is to order the data by the completeness of data in columns, firstly goes most filled column and so on, lastly by name. If columns have same number of filled values, priority go in following order `pass` > `run` > `catch` > `player_name`. Columns `pass`, `run`, `catch` should be ordered in descending order, column `player_name` - is ascending order.

For instant, the output shd be sth like;

```
player_name|pass|run|catch

Ryan Giggs| 35|NULL|30
Wayne Rooney|30|400|40
Gareth Bale |30|500|20
Sergio Ramos|28|200|40
```

I came up with two suitable approaches to solve this problem, am sure there can be more.

**Approach 1**

```
set @Q=concat('select * from player_statistics order by ',
                  
            (select group_concat(N, 'desc') from (
            select 'pass '  N, count(pass)  C from player_statistics
                union
            select 'run '   N, count(run)   C from player_statistics
                union
            select 'catch ' N, count(catch) C from player_statistics
            order by C DESC) Z),
                  
            ',player_name');


    prepare S FROM @Q;
    execute S;
```

Good news is that this approach is working fine. As you can see, I am defining a variable here and assigning a SQL string to this variable. Later preparing and executing this statement.

Here comes my next approach;

**Approach 2**

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
    SELECT 'pass' name, COUNT(pass) c FROM player_statistics
    UNION
    SELECT 'run', COUNT(run) FROM player_statistics
    UNION
    SELECT 'catch', COUNT(catch) FROM player_statistics
    ORDER BY c DESC)
    
    SET @q = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM playerStatistics 
    ORDER BY ", (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name," DESC") FROM CTE1), ", player_name");
    
    prepare S FROM @q;
    execute S;
```

As seen, here I first define a CTE and then use both the base table as well as the CTE in the SQL string. Overall both the approaches seem to be implementing same methodology. But with my second approach, I'm getting following error;

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) in the pre-written template: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check      the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @q = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM playerStatistics 
ORDER BY ", (SELECT GROUP_C' at line 11
```

May I get some feedback what might be going wrong with my syntax in the second approach. Notice that we are using mySql 8.0.22. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the problem description, not the link to it. Specify DBMS and its precise version.

Comment: @Akina. Appreciate your. response. I have tried to add more details. Feel free to look into the problem. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: *The goal is to order the data by the completeness of data in columns, firstly goes most filled column and so on, lastly by name. For instant, the output shd be sth like;* The output looks like `ORDER BY pass, player_name DESC`. For example. I think that precise expression for the "completeness" (or detailed explanation at least) must be added.

Comment: `with` needs to be followed by `select` I believe, so I think the error is caused by use of `set` where a select is expected.